# Add a GUI to class

Tags: java, user-interface, bluej

I want to know how to add a GUI to my program. I have started creating a java program in Blue J and the first class of the program is a class which has been extended by other classes.

Now I have to make a GUI too but from my understanding I can only implement an interface as the GUI extends the class Frame. The problem is I want to create a GUI of my class, it has instance variables too so is there a  work around? Could I make my first class an interface without altering the extensions too much?

code:

```
public class Players /* Class name */
{

    private int attack; /* Instance variables* */
    private int defence;
    private int jump;

    public Players(int a, int d, int j) /* Constructor being defined */
    {
        int total = a + d + j;
        if((total) == 100)
        {
            attack = a;
            defence = d;
            jump = j;
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Make stats add to 100");
        }
    }

    public Players()/* Default contructor if not user defined */
    {
        attack = 34;
        defence = 33;
        jump = 33;
    }

    public void addAttack(int a)
    {
        attack += a;
    }

    public void addDefence(int a)
    {
        defence += a;
    }

    public void addJump(int a)
    {
        jump += a;
    }

    public void getBasicStats()
    {
        System.out.println(attack + " " + defence + " " + jump);
    }
}
```

This is my first class and my superclass for most of the other classes

Comment: For quicker help post source code.

Comment: @VaibhavG Of course, apologies

Comment: Your class does not have to be the UI class, create the UI just as show in the [tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/) and use your class in it.

Comment: Unrelated, but the funky indentation makes the code harder to read.

Comment: @a4l So can I create the GUI and then relate it to my class later?

Comment: @DaveNewton lol sorry, I find the conventional way difficult

Comment: @A4L thats good, will the gui codes be inside this class?

Comment: Which class? Create a separate class for the GUI and declare an instance variable of your class inside the GUI class and use use it for all the actions you want your GUI to perform.

Comment: @a4l How will I declare aan instance variable inside the GUI class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How will I declare aan instance variable inside the GUI class?

Like as shown bellow, you could start with something like this, note that your application should be able to hand out your data to other classes, for instance I changed `getBasicStats()` to return a `String`, this way you can use your application class anywhere you want, I guess this is why you were confused about where to place the GUI code...

```
public class PlayersGUI extends JFrame {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private Players players; // instance variable of your application

    private PlayersGUI() {
        players = new Players();
        initGUI();
    }

    private void initGUI() {
        setTitle("This the GUI for Players application");
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(640, 560));
        setLocation(new Point(360, 240));

        JPanel jPanel = new JPanel();
        JLabel stat = new JLabel(players.getBasicStats());

        JButton attack = new JButton("Attack!");
        attack.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                players.addAttack(1);
            }
        });

        JButton hugeAttack = new JButton("HUGE Attack!");
        hugeAttack.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                players.addAttack(10);
            }
        });

        JButton defend = new JButton("Defend");
        defend.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                players.addDefence(1);
            }
        });

        JButton showStats = new JButton("Show stats");
        showStats.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                stat.setText(players.getBasicStats());
            }
        });

        jPanel.add(stat);
        jPanel.add(attack);
        jPanel.add(hugeAttack);
        jPanel.add(defend);
        jPanel.add(showStats);

        add(jPanel);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    public static void main(String... args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                PlayersGUI pgui = new PlayersGUI();
                pgui.pack();
                pgui.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I suggest learning how to use Swing. You will have several different classes interacting together. In fact, it is considered good practice to keep separate the code which creates and manages the GUI from the code which performs the underlying logic and data manipulation.

Answer (score 1):

Another suggestion: 
Learn JavaFX and download SceneBuilder from  Oracle: [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/sb2download-2177776.html)
At my university they have stopped teaching Swing and started to teach JavaFX, saying JavaFX has taken over the throne from Swing.

SceneBuilder is very easy to use, drag and drop concept. It creates a FXML file which is used to declare your programs GUI.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using netbeans to start with. From there you can easily select pre created classes such as Jframes. Much easier to learn. You can create a GUI from there by dragging and dropping buttons and whatever you need.

Here is a youtube tut to create GUI's in netbeans.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LFr06ZKIpSM

If you decide not to go with netbeans, you are gonna have to create swing containers withing your class to make the Interface.

Comment: I will give this a go too

Comment: Totally misread your post, though point still stands what you are trying to do would be easier to manage in Netbeans.

Comment: Unfortunately I am requirered to use BlueJ

Comment: As mentioned above, create a separate class for the GUI, and import or export the data you need to or from the GUI. The way your are gonna do it all depends on what type of data you are getting setting or storing.